# Using CSS selectors, change the element wrapping text

Tags: html, css

I currently have:

```
<span> Hello </span>
```

I want to use CSS selectors to replace or wrap the text within the element with an

```
<h1>
```

without using anything but CSS selectors.

Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to change the element to basically be `<h1>Hello</h1>`?

Comment: No you can't change HTML from CSS. But you can make the span look like a heading by changing font size and weight... That is what CSS is perfect for.

Comment: @GolezTrol though that wouldn't actually make it a heading, which would have quite serious implications for any blind document parser, such as an search engine or screen reader - it would be better to do this with JS, or by editing the HTML

Comment: If it needs to be a heading for screen readers, just make it a heading (server side). You can use JavaScript, but screen readers (and search engines) don't always respond well to JavaScript changing the DOM either. Many of them won't execute JavaScript at all. And the question is, should it *work* like a heading or should it only *look* like a heading? I think the answer currently isn't written clearly enough to determine what exactly is needed.

Comment: @GolezTrol I would say if it needs to look like a heading, then it almost certainly is a heading and there'd be a lot of benefit in rendering it as such - the server would be the best place (or in the web component view layer) though I think the [robots are getting better at handling JS](http://a11yproject.com/posts/myth-screen-readers-dont-use-javascript/), it's just the CSS they won't bother with

Comment: But... this is all conjecture because the OP hasn't stated whether they want it to act like a heading or look like a heading.

Comment: @TinyGiant this is true, which is why it's a comment - though it's also something important for the OP to think about, H1 is important

Comment: I agree. The question is unclear. I'll retract my close vote if the OP clarifies their question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not actually possible to change the element in CSS, but you can simulate the effect of turning `<span>Hello</span>` into `<h1>Hello</h1>` in just CSS by adding properties to the `span` part of your CSS. You should do something like this.

```
span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.67em;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm8shtm3/2/)

As pointed out in the comments, this will not give the span the other properties of an `h1` tag. To actually do this, you can do something like this in Javascript:

```
var mySpan = document.getElementById("span");
var myH1 = document.createElement("h1");
myH1.innerHTML = mySpan.innerHTML;
myAnchor.parentNode.replaceChild(myH1, mySpan);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm8shtm3/5/)

Comment: it's worth pointing out that this simulates the visual effect only, not the other effects of H1 which are actually quite important, such as for search engines and screen readers

Comment: @ToniLeigh I've edited that in, as well as the way to actually do it in JS.